# Clicking a button triggers an onClick() for the div, and stopPropagation only triggers once. Why only once?

Tags: javascript, function, click, listener, stoppropagation

I have a `div` element that when clicked, creates another `div` and a `button`. When clicked, the first div should create the second div (an overlay) and once the close button is pressed, the overlay should close. I want this process to be repeatable, but the problem I am currently facing is that it only works once.

IE:
I click on the div, and an overlay with a button shows up. I click the button to close the overlay, and it goes away. Then I click on the div again, and again the overlay with a button shows up. But this time when I press the close button, it simply opens another overlay. How can I stop this from happening? I am at a loss, please help.

```
async function addClickListener2(div, imageName, tag) {
    div.addEventListener('click', async function () {  // closes on X button click, but opens again right away
        if (this.className === 'card loaded') {
            const overlay = document.createElement('div'); // create div 'overlay'
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            overlay.id = 'overlay'; // assign id for css
            div.appendChild(overlay); // append to clicked div so overlay isn't at top of page
            overlay.style.display = 'block'; // make overlay visible
            overlay.innerText = JSON.stringify(await getManifest(imageName, tag));
            button.id = 'overlayButton';
            button.innerText = 'X';
            overlay.appendChild(button);
            overlayCloseButton();
        }
    })
}

function overlayCloseButton() {
    document.getElementById('overlayButton').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Only works once
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this question will be useful to anyone else, I've solved the problem by simply deleting the overlay, instead of hiding it using `.remove()`.

```
    div.addEventListener('click', async function () { 
        if (this.className === 'card loaded') {
            const pre = document.createElement('pre');
            const overlay = document.createElement('div'); // create div 'overlay'
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            overlay.id = 'overlay'; // assign id for css
            document.body.appendChild(overlay); 
            pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(await getManifest(imageName, tag), null, 2);
            button.id = 'overlayButton';
            button.innerText = 'X';
            overlay.appendChild(button);
            overlay.appendChild(pre);
            addOverlayCloseHandler();
        }
    })
}

function addOverlayCloseHandler() {
    document.getElementById('overlayButton').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('overlay').remove();
    })
}
```